# How to use ternary operator when you structure object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am pushing object to array based on data so properties are changing dynamically trying to map the property value which comes in data , two options here data could come as `data.type.elementType.name` or `data.type.name` how to use ternary operator to assign either value ?

main.js

```js
if (item.type.declaration.signatures.length !== 0) {
  var responseData = item.type.declaration.signatures[0].parameters[0].type.declaration.children;
  for (var data of responseData) {
    if (data.name === "details") {
      var detailsName = name === data.type.elementType.name ? data.type.elementType.name : data.type.name;
      interfaceModules.push({ id: "details", name: detailsName });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `data.type.elementType.name ?` should most likely be `data.type.elementType ?`.  If the elementType doesn't exist, trying to `.name` off of it would be a null pointer exception

Comment: And what is `name` here at ternary comparison `name === data.type.elementType.name ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a ternary, I believe you will need to take the `.name` off of the conditional to avoid the exception of trying to access a property on a null element.

```
var detailsName = name === data.type.elementType ? data.type.elementType.name : data.type.name;
```

Another option could be to use the elementType if it exists, otherwise use the type, to then get the name.

```
var detailsName = name === ( data.type.elementType || data.type ).name;
```

Comment: actually when data come as `data.type.elementType.name` its throwing undefined `detailsName`

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: firs version in the answer